Local–global principle for powers of rational numbers.
We know that for a rational number, 'being $n$-th power' satisfy local-global principle.
$\textbf{My question: }$ Given a positive integer $n$ and finitely many positive rational number $\{a_1, a_2, ..., a_k\}$ such that $a_i \notin \mathbb{Q}^{*n} \; \forall \ i$. Does there exist a prime(non-Archimedean place) $\nu$ such that $a_i \notin \mathbb{Q}_{\nu}^{*n} \; \forall \ i?$
If this is not true in general, what is the best known positive result in this direction?

The Grunwald–Wang theorem is the best possible result in this direction.
